# Couldn't match expected type `Integer' against inferred type `Value'

Tags: haskell

I am trying to implement the following code in Haskell, to evaluate an Arithmetic Expression, unfortunately it give me the error `` Couldn't match expected type `Integer' against inferred type `Value' `` at `(IVal (eval c x)) + (IVal (eval c (Prim IntAddOp xs)))).`
Plz help me with some solution.

```
     type Env = GenEnv Value

    data Value
         = IVal Integer
         | BVal Bool

    -------------------------------------------------- 
     eval :: Env -> Exp -> Value
     eval _ (Num n) = IVal n
     eval _ (Prim IntAddOp ((Num x) : (Num y):[])) = IVal (x+y)
     eval c (Prim IntAddOp (x: xs)) =  IVal  ((IVal (eval c x)) + (IVal (eval c 
                                        (Prim IntAddOp xs))))
```

Thank you...

Answer (score 4):

The last line should be changed:

```
IVal $ 
  case eval c x of
    IVal ix ->
      case eval c (Prim IntAddOp xs) of
        IVal ip -> ix + ip
        _       -> error "trying to add int value to bool value"
    _       -> error "trying to add bool value to int value"
```

(Or something similar.  You didn't provide all the definitions of the data structures to be sure.)

However, this can be tidied up some more.  Further, you never seem to use the Env parameter.

EDIT:  Here's a nicer way of doing it.  Note we're working in the Maybe monad: adding a boolean value to an integer value makes no sense.

```
eval :: Expression -> Maybe Value
eval (Integer i) = return $ IVal i
eval (Boolean b) = return $ BVal b
eval (Add   l r) =
  do el <- eval l
     er <- eval r
     return . IVal $ l + r
eval (And   l r) =
  do el <- eval l
     er <- eval r
     return . BVal $ l && r
... and so on
```

If you want error messages, replace the Maybe with the error monad.

Answer (score 2):

This error means exactly what it says.

**First of all, what did Haskell expect?**

```
IVal ( something )
```

Haskell expects `something` to be an `Integer`, because your definition of `Value` said it should be:

```
data Value
     = IVal Integer
     | BVal Bool
```

**Second of all, what did Haskell infer?**

```
(IVal (eval c x)) + (IVal (eval c (Prim IntAddOp xs)))
```

I have to assume you've defined a `Num` instance for `Value`s, otherwise `+` wouldn't work. So when you add a `Value` to an `Value`, you should get an `Value` result. (I know that the two things being added are `Values` because `IVal` is a constructor for the `Value` type)

So Haskell infers that this expression has the type `Value`.

**Why don't they match?**

Haskell is expecting an `Integer` expression, and you gave it a `Value` expression. The error means exactly what it says. So how to fix it? Well, I have no clue. Taking a stab in the dark, you could remove the `IVal` constructors from the addition.

```
( (eval c x) + (eval c (Prim IntAddOp xs)) )
```

Wait a minute, the result of `eval` is a `Value`, not an `Integer`, so...we're still adding `Values`, and wrapping these in an `IVal` is even more wrong than it was before.

How about we define a function to get the `Integer` out of an `IVal`.

```
extract :: Value -> Integer
extract (IVal x) = x
extract (BVal True) = 1
extract (BVal False) = 0
```

Here I'm using the horrendous C-like convention of treating booleans as 1 or 0. You might want to leave `extract` undefined on `BVal`s, or throw an error, or whatever. At least now we have a way of extracting an `Integer` from a `Value`.

So now I'm assuming that you actually *don't* have a `Num` instance for `Value`. Let's just extract the `Integers` out of those two expressions in order to add them together.

```
( extract (eval c x) + extract (eval c (Prim IntAddOp xs)) )
```

Now *that* should be inferred to be an `Integer`. So then we can wrap it in an `IVal` constructor.

```
IVal (extract (eval c x) + extract (eval c (Prim IntAddOp xs)))
```

Problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

```
 eval _ (Prim _ ([])) = IVal (0)

 eval _ (Prim IntAddOp ((Num x) : (Num y):[])) = IVal (x+y)
 eval s (Prim IntAddOp (x: xs)) =  IVal  (test (eval s x)+  test (eval s (Prim IntAddOp 
   xs)))
```

This works fine it is evaluating 1+2+3=...;

Thanks for you help guys.......